# OpenMDAO handling errors within groups

Tags: genetic-algorithm, openmdao

I am trying to run an optimization with SimpleGADriver in OpenMDAO. My model includes a cycle (subsystem) with a nonlinear solver, that contains a component that on occasions fails to compute its response. Is there any way to make this driver continue to the next iteration (iteration of the driver) on encountering this error, i.e., is there any way to break the nonlinear solver's solution and proceed with the next iteration of the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your component knows when it fails to compute its response, it can raise an `om.AnalysisError`.  When the SimpleGADriver detects this, it will mark this as a failed point and move on to the next point to evaluate in the current generation. However, if you have nested nonlinear solvers (i.e., solvers in more than one group in the hierarchy above your component), then you also need to set `reraise_child_analysiserror` to True in those solvers.

I looked through our documentation, and there isn't an example of this, but you can see AnalysisError usage in this test:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/test_suite/components/ae_tests.py

You can also see a nested solver case with `reraise_child_analysiserror` in this test:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/3460c29adba3b280fba84addd16a56036b9332ad/openmdao/solvers/nonlinear/tests/test_nonlinear_block_gs.py#L24

Comment: Thanks you, that's exactly what I have been looking for. Just to clarify, what does this implementation of GA do with the failed points? Does it set artificially high/low fitness function to discourage it, or does it just skip these point completely and computes a next one to replace it?

Comment: That's exactly what it does-- sets the fitness to np.inf.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can I also ask if there's any way to printout/save to file the value of the fitness at each point/iteration of the driver? That would help me to tune the penalty parameters

Comment: We don't have a direct way to do that. Though, you can add a case recorder to the driver, which would get you the objective and constraint values for all evaluated points.  To get the fitness with constraint penalty, you'll have to do some additional calculations.

Comment: All clear, thank you.